# python - Scan through a large file and write lines when conditions met

Tags: python, vcf-vcard

I was trying to scan with positions from one file through positions in second file to find, if the features are overlaping between them.

I have a file Pt looking like this:

```
chr10   0   60985
chr10   60988   60990
chr1    165014865   165014867
chr1    1161693 1161695
chr1    158851689 158851689
chr10   64766   64767
chr10   63600   64703
chr11   647696  647697
```

And file a (it has of course many many lines like the one below):

```
chr1    1161693 chr1uGROUPERuDELu0u832  TGCTCTTTCCAGAAACCCTCAACCCTGTACGGTCAGGAGGAAACATGGCACCTCCCCTCTGGGG    T   63  NormalSupport;MinSampleCount;LowSomaticScore    CLUSTER_NUM=5454;CONTIG=GGTGCAGGGAAGCAGGAAGGAAGTGAAGCTCAAAAGCCCCTAGGACAGGGCACCTCCCCTCTGGATGCTCTTTCCAGAAACCCTCAACCTTGTACGGTCAGGAGAAAACACATCCCACAAG;CONTIG_NUM=5840;DOWNSTREAM=GCTCTTTCCAGAAACCCTCAACCCTGTACGGTCAGGAGAAAACACATCCCACAAG;END=1161756;NS=1;READSOURCES=(0:3:0,1:2:13);SOMATICSCORE=19;SVLEN=-63;SVTYPE=DEL;UPSTREAM=GGTGCAGGGAAGCGGGAAGGAAGTGAAGCTCAAAAGCCCCTAGGACAGGGCACCTCCCCTCTGGAT;ensembl_gene_id=ENSG00000078808   GT:GQ   1/.:.
chr1    158851689   chr1uGROUPERuDELu3u4452 GGGGAGTAATTCTTATTCATGATATGAAAACTCTAATGTGTTTCTTATTCCAGAAAA   G   100 NormalSupport   CLUSTER_NUM=25182;CONTIG=CATATTTTGCTATATCTCACATCATTGTTCATCTGATAATATATGAAAACTACAATGTGTTTCTTATTCCAGAAAGGGGAGTAATTCTTATTCATGAATAAACACTGAAGGAGAAAGATTATGGATCATAGTGGGAAAAGCCACAATACCATCTACATTC;CONTIG_NUM=24300;DOWNSTREAM=GGGAGTAATTCTTATTCATGAATAAACACTGACGGAGAAAGATTATGGATCATAGTGGGAAAAGCCACAATACCATCTACATTC;END=158851745;NS=1;READSOURCES=(0:11:0,1:3:18);SOMATICSCORE=55;SVLEN=-56;SVTYPE=DEL;UPSTREAM=CATATTTTGCTATATCTCACATCATTGTTCATCTGATAATATATGAAAACTCCAATGTGTTTCTTATTCCAGAAAG;ensembl_gene_id=ENSG00000229849    GT:GQ   1/.:.
chr1    165014865   chr1uGROUPERuDELu3u7344 ACTGGCATTAGCTATGCTTCCTTAGGCAGACAGCATGTTGAGAAATTCACATTCATCAG A   100 NormalSupport   CLUSTER_NUM=40249;CONTIG=CTCCAGTAAAGAGCATCTTTTAATGAAGTGTATCTGCCTGGGCTAGAAAGGCAGCTGCCTCCACTAAAGCAGGGCTGGTCCAGAAATATTACCACTTGCCTAATCCTTATAGTAATCCTAACTGGCAGGTATTATTATATCCCAATTCACACACTTAGAGG;CONTIG_NUM=38845;DOWNSTREAM=CTTGCCTAATCCTTATAGTAATCCTAACTGGCAGGTATTATTATATCCCAATTCACACACTTAGAGG;END=165014923;NS=1;READSOURCES=(0:32:0,1:9:18);SOMATICSCORE=60;SVLEN=-58;SVTYPE=DEL;UPSTREAM=CTCCAGTAAAGAGCATCTTTTAATGAAGTGTATCTGCCTGGGCTAGAAAGGCAGCTGCCTCCACTAAAGCAGGGCTGGTCCAGAAATATTACCA  GT:GQ   1/.:.
chr1    176569763   chr1uGROUPERuDELu3u12313    GATCGCGCCACTGCACTCCAGCCTGGGCGACAGAGCGAGACTCCGTCTCAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA G   100 NormalSupport;LowSomaticScore   CLUSTER_NUM=65333;CONTIG=GCGTGGTAGCGGGCGCCTGTAGTCCCAGCTACTCGGGAGGCTGAGGCAGGAGAATGGCGTGAACCCGGGAGGCGGAGCTTGCAGTGAGCCGAGATCACAGAGCTCAAGCTCACAATTCCATTATACTGTTACTC;CONTIG_NUM=62936;DOWNSTREAM=ATCACAGAGCTCAAGCTCACAATTCCATTATACTGTTACTC;END=176569833;NS=1;READSOURCES=(0:14:0,1:8:7);SOMATICSCORE=22;SVLEN=-70;SVTYPE=DEL;UPSTREAM=GCGTGGTAGCGGGCGCCTGTAGTCCCAGCTACTCGGGAGGCTGAGGCAGGAGAATGGCGTGAACCCGGGAGGCGGAGCTTGCAGTGAGCCGAG;ensembl_gene_id=ENSG00000116183 GT:GQ   1/.:.
chr1    184683773   chr1uGROUPERuDELu3u15990    TAACAGTTTGGATGAAAAAAATGTAAGGTATGCTCATCTAAACTATAGATCATTGAAAACTGGTAGTTTAGCTAATGAGATTCAACCTCTAGACCAAAATCTAGAAACAAAACAAAAAAAGAAATTTTGCTGAGTTAAATATAAAAGTTCTAAGTTTACACTAAAAAAAAGAA   T   93  PASS    CLUSTER_NUM=82731;CONTIG=TAAACCACCACATGCAAAGAGCCTGTAACTGAAAGCTCTTGAGTGCAGTGCCACAAGGCACTGGTTGGGGTCCAACCAAAACTTCTTCCTAACTTGGCTGCTCAAAGGCAGGGTGGAGAACACTCATTTGTCAGCAGACCATAC;CONTIG_NUM=79822;DOWNSTREAM=AACTTGGCTGCTCAAAGGCAGGGTGGAGAACACTCATTTGTCAGCAGACCATAC;END=184683945;NS=1;READSOURCES=(0:12:46,1:0:44);SOMATICSCORE=30;SVLEN=-172;SVTYPE=DEL;UPSTREAM=TAAACCACCACATGCAAAGAGCCTGTAACTGAAAGCTCTTGAGTGCAGTGCCACAAGGCACTGGTTGGGGTCCAACCAAAACTTCTTCCT;ensembl_gene_id=ENSG00000116406  GT:GQ   1/.:.
chr1    193557238   chr1uGROUPERuDELu3u20250    TGTGTGTATACACACACACACATATATGTGTGTATACACACACACACATATATATATGTGTGTATACACACACACACATATATATGTGTGTATACACACAC   T   100 NormalSupport   CLUSTER_NUM=103112;CONTIG=TTTAAAATAAGGGGGGAAATTTATATATATATATATATATATATGTGTGTGTGTATACACACACACATATATATATATACACACACACATATATATATATATACACATACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACTGTTTGAAATA;CONTIG_NUM=99338;DOWNSTREAM=ACATATATATATATGTGTGTATACACACACACATATATATATATACACACACACATATATATATATACACATACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACTGTTTGAAATA;END=193557338;NS=1;READSOURCES=(0:23:0,1:3:26);SOMATICSCORE=60;SVLEN=-100;SVTYPE=DEL;UPSTREAM=TTTAAAATAAGGGGGGAAATTTATATATATATAT    GT:GQ   1/.:.
chr1    211021468   chr1uGROUPERuDELu4u5565 ACAAGCTGTTGGGTTATCTCTTTATGATCTTCAACTACACTAAGAAGTGTGTCAATTGTATTCAGAATTCCCATAGCAGTAACTGCTTTGTCATCACTACCTTCTTCATCTGGCCCTGTCTGGATTACTTGGCTAAATGTCATTGCCAACTGTTGTGTCATTTCTACTGCAATAGGAGTAACTTCTTCACTATTTTCACAGATCATTTTCTGAATTACATTGGTAAGGTCATCATTTTCTGTTTCTGTTATAATATGAAGAAGAGCCTGCATTACAGGTCTGATAAATGCTGTGATACATTCTTTAGATTTTTCTTGATTGCTGATAAATACTTGAAGGACAATGGCAGCTTCCACTTTCACAGGCATGTCTCTGTCATCAATCAGACATCTTCTTGTTAGCTCTAAAGCTGTTTGAATGTTCTGATCACTTTTGAACTTTACTTCACAAAAATAGTGAAGTACTCAGCAAGCCCTTGCTCTCATGTAGCCTAGTTCACTGCTGAAGAGAGAGAACACATGATTCTGCAACATGTATTCCATCTGATCATTACAGATCTTTTTCTTCAGAAGTGTTTCAGCTAAAGAGCCAATCATGCAGGGCTCCATCTTTTTTTCAAAGGTCAGCATTGGGTTCTGTAAGAATCTGGTAACAAAATCCCATAGTCTTTTGAAGTACCTCCTTCCTCTTACTATGGGCTGTAAACAAAAGCTTCTGGGCAGCAGTGGCAAAGGAAATGAAATCTTCAGACACATCAAACTTCATGCGTATATACTCGTAAGGGTCTTCTTCCCAAAGTTCCTCATCAGCATCTGTATAACACATCAATGGAAAAATAACATCTTGGATAATGCCTTGTATATGGGGCTTCAGATTCTTCCAGGTGAGAGCATGAGAAACTCCTTGATTAATAGAATTTAATGTCTGTTGTAAAACTTGAGGAGCCATATATTGCTTCTCGTTGTACTGTTATAACACTTTCAATAAAACTTGCTGGACACCAACAACAAATTCCTTCAGAAATACTTGAGCAAATTCATTATACTCCTAGGAAACACTGCCAGAGCTTCCATATCTTTCAAAAAGTCTTGCTAAAATATGTAAGGCCCACTTCTTGCATTTCCATTATGATAACTCAGGTCGGTCATCTTCTTCAATTCGAAGTGTTTCAGTCTTTAAAATTTCTACCCATTCTGTCAGGTTCTGTTGGTTTATCAGTTCCAGTGGTATAGAGTATAGAGTATATACTGAACAAGAGCATAGAGTATATACTGAACAAGATCATAGAAGATCTTGAATATTTGTTTCTGGATGACGACAGACTGATCAGACTGGTCAGAAAGAAGCTGGATAAAATGATCCTTTAGAACTGACAGAAAATGCTGCATTGCTGCTACCAATGGACTCCACTCCTCTAGTTTTTTATACTCATAAGTTTTCACAAGCTGATAAAGGCAAATAATTCCTATCCAACAAGCACTGTTATCACACTGAAGATAAAAGCCAGTTTTGTCCACAATGGCAGTCCAGCAGCTTGGATAATCACGTTTGGTGATGTGATGAATGCATGTAGTAAGCTGTACCCTGATGAGCTCAGGAGGATGGATAATGGCTTCTACAATATTTTCTCAAATACAATGGCAATCTTCTTCTGGAATAGTATAAGGGGATATATACTTTTGTGCTGTTTCTTGACCAGGCCAATACTGTGTTATATTTTTCAAATAGATAACACCTGCCTGTCTCACAGGTAAATCCAGCTGTTCCGACATAGTAATCTGGAGCAGCGTTGAGACAAAATTCAGAGATTTGTGTGCTTCATTGAGCTGGCGCTCCATGGCCTCTTGCAGGGCTGGGTCCATGGTGCCCCGCAGGGCCTCGATAATGGTGTTGGGGTCCATTGCAGCATGAACTAGGTCAAACCCAGGGCTTGAGTGCTACTGGGCCAGGAATAGCACTACTCACTGCACACATGGACCTGCCGCAGCGGCAACTGGCGCAAAAGGGCAATGGTGCAATCTTAACTCACTGTAACCTTGAACTCCTGGGCTCAAGTGATCCTCCCACCTCAGCCTCCCAAGTAGCTGGGACTGCAGGCTCACGCTACCATGCCAAGCTGATTTTGTGTTGTTGTAGAGATAGGGTCTCACTATGTTGCCCAGGCTGGTCTTGAACTCCTGGTCTTAAGCAATCATCCTGCATCAGCCTCCCAAAGTGCTGGATTTACAAGCCTGAGTCACCATGCCTGGCCAATATTTTCAATAGTTAGAGGCAGGATTGAAAAACAATTCCTTTTTGCTTTGCTCAAAATAAGTATTTATGAGCATCCACTTACGAGTTACTGTGCTAGATGCTGGACATACAAATAGAAATAAGACCCAGTTACTGCTGTTGTGGAAAGGGCAACATTAGAGAAATGTTCAGGAAATGGAGGAAAGGCCCTTATCTCAGCTTAAGGAAGCCTTAACTCACTATTGTTTGGCTGAATCTCAAAAATGTACAAACCAATAGGAGTGTCCCCTTCTTCCCTACAGATTCCCTGAAGCCAGTGGGCTGTCTGGCAGGAAAACCAAATACTAACTGTGATTTGCCCATTCTAGAAGGTAAGAGAAGGGATTCAGGGCATGCGTGTAAAGTTAGGCTTTGATGACTTGTGTTAGAAGGTTCAGGAAGAAAGCCGCATCACTTATCCCCTATGGAAAAAAAGGAATGGCCAAGAGAACTTCCTTGAATCCATGAAGAGCTTCCAAAAAGAGAAATTTTAAGTTTAGGGATGATAAGGAGCAGAAAGGCTTGGTCTGCTTTACCTGGTGAGCCTATCAATGCACCCACCAAGCACATGCTTGTTACCCAGCAGAGTGTTGGGCACTAGGGGGTGGAGGAGGATAGAATCTAAGATTACTTTTAGCTCTGAAAATCTCAAGACCATCTAAGTTAGGCTCTTCATTTTACAAAAGACAAAGTGCAGACCCAGAAAAGGCCTTATCCAAAATCACATTACTAGCTCTTGAGTACAAGATTACTAGCAGGCTGCAATCTGGGAAGATGGCTGAAGTGGACTTGACATCATATTAAACTCCAGCATCAGTACTTTGGGCAACATGTAGTCACCAGAGGTCTCTGAGCTGGTGACCAGCTTAGTTAAAACCACTTTCCCCCTTGATAATAGTAAATGCCATTTCCAGTTAAGTTACAGATGACAGATTTTATGGAATGTTTCCACCTTAATGTGCGAGATCTGAATGGTACCTCCATCACTGACATTACATTTTGTTTCTCAACCCTCCTCTTCACAGCTCTTATTAGGAAATCGGGGAAAGTCAGGTGCTGAGGCCCAAAGGAGCTGTGCCTTGCTGGTGTTCCCTCATGAAAGGCTGCAGCCAGAACTGTGTCCTTCCTTCTCAATGCAGGTCTCTATGCTAAACTTGTTCACCCTCTGTTCCAGAGCTTTAGGTGCTCCACACGAAGTACTCTTGAACTCTGTCAACCCTGACCTCTCCCCTGTCATGTAGAAAGGCCTCAAGTGGTAGTTTTTGGAGCTCCCGATCATACAAGCACATGCACCCTTCTCAGGAGAGGGCAATTAGGAAACCTGCTGCTAACTAGAGGTGCCATGGCAGGTGCCAACTGGATCAGTGCAGGATGGAACAGCACATTCCAGACAGCCTCATGAGTTCATTGCTAAGGGTAGAGCTAATTTACAGGAAACATGCAGAGGGTTTGACTGGATCCCCTCTGATACCAGCTGAGCCCAGCTCTCACATGCCTATGGCATGGAGTGGATGGTGCTGGGGCAGGCTTCTCTCAGCCTGACAGCAGAGTAGCTGTCTCCACTATTGAGCCAGGTGTGACCCCAGAATGCCATCTCTACCCCCTCAGCATGGTAGCAATGCCACGGCAGTGAGGATGTGGGGAATGAGGAGCAGCTTAGGAGAGACTAAGGCATTGCAGGACTGAGGTCCACTATGCAGCTCCAGGTCCCCCTACTATGCTCCTTCAAGAACAGTGTTGGTAGTAAGAGATTATCACCAAGTTCCTCTCAACTCAGCAAAACAAGTGGGGAAGCGAGAAAACAAAGGAGGAGGAAGATAGCTTCCTGTGCTGTGAGGACTAATTGCAAGCAAAATATGTGTCAGCTGCCACTGCTCACAGTAAACACTCAACGGATGGTAACCCTAAGGGTTTGGGCTGCAGCTTTAGTGCCCAAATCCTACCTCTATGGAGGGAGTGAGACACTTGGACAACAACAATCAAGGCAGGTGGAGAAAATTCTGGTTTTGCTTGTCCCAAAACAAATCACCTCACCCATAGCAGTGTAAGACAACTAGCATTTTACTATGTTCACAGATTCTGAGCACGAGAAATTTAGAAAAGGCCCAGCAGGATGGCTTGTCTCTCTTTCTTATACCTGGAGCCTCAGCCGGAAAGATTCAAAGACTGGGATGACTTAGTTGGAATCATCTATGAGCCAGTTCATTCACATAACTGGTGGTTGACCCATGCTGTCAGCTAGAACCTGAAGCTGTAAGCTGGAACACCTATACATGGCCCTTCCATGTGGCTCTTTGAATTTCTTTACAGAATGGTAGCTGGGTTCTAAGAGCAGGTGTCCCAAACAAATCACACAGAATCTGTATGACCTTTGATGACTTAGCCTATCACTATAATGTGACTTCTGCCATAGCCACAAGGCTTTCCAGGTTCAAGGGTAGAGAACAAGTATCAAAGGCAAATTTTTAGAAGAACATGTGGAATGGAAGGTAATGTTAAAGCTATCTCTGGAATATACAATCTGCTTCATTTGTCAAGCTAAACATATGCCCCCATAGTCTCCCAATGCAGAGATATTATGTACAATGTCTGGAACAAATATTTTCATATGACAGCTCATTAATTCAGTCCTTACAATAATACTGCAAGGTAATTTATTATTACTCCACGTTTTACCTGAAACTGAGCTCAAAAAGTTTAGATAACTTGACCAAGGTCATATAGTTTTTAAGCACCAAAGCAGTATCAAATCCAGATCTAAATCTGTTAACTACTTGTTAAAACTCAAAGCTCATAGTCTTTAGAGAACATTTTGGGTCAAACTAAATGATCTTGGTTCTAGGGCAGTAGGAATAAGGTAGCAAAGAAAAAAAAAAGGCAGCTGTTCATTTGATGCCTAAATGTTCACAGTGTACACACAATGCTGAAGCTACGCTTTGTAACTCTTAAGTGTTATTTCTTTTGCTAATAAATGCATTTTATGTAAGGAAAGACTTTGAAAAACAGTATCTCCAGATAGAATGGAAGCTGGGCCACCTTGCTAGGCTCTCCTACACCCCAATCGCATTTTCCAAAGTAGGGAGAAAGGTACAGTTCAGAACCTCTGTTTTTCAAACTGGAATAAGGCCTCTCTCTTACTTTTCCCCCAACTCTTTAAGACAGACAGTTTTTATTTTGAAACTTGGCCTAGATTGTGGGGCAAAGCACAACCAAATGAAATGGGTGAATTCCCATTTTGATCCTTATTGTCATTCTCCATCTCAGGTAGCTGATGGATCCAGGCTAAATGTGGGTCAAAAAGTATGTTATAGATCAGCTTTAGTTGAAAAAAAATGTGTATACACCAATACAACTCAATGGGGGAATAAAAACTTTTTCAACAAATAGTGTTAAGACAACTGGATATCTGCATGCAAGTGAATGAAGTTGGACCCCTACCTCACACCATACACAAAATTTAACTCAAAATGGATGATAGTCTTAATTGTAAGAACTAATGCTCTAAAACTCTTAGATGAAAATATAGGGGCAAATCTTTATGACCCTGAGTTAGGCAAAGCCTTTTTAATTGTGACACCAAAAGTACAGTCTACAGAAGAAAACTAGAAAAAATGGACTATATGAAAACCTAAACTTTTGTACTGCAAAAGATACCATCAAGCTAGTAAAAAATGCAACCCACAGACTCGCAGAAAATATTTGCAAATAAAATACCTTATAAGAGATTTGTATCCAGAATATATTACAAAAAACTCATAACTCAATAGTGAAAAAATAACCCAATTAAAAATAGGCAAAGAATCTAAATAGACATTTCTCCAAAGAAGATATAGAAATGGCCAATAAGCACATGAAAAGATGTTCAACATCCCTAGTCATACGGGAAATGCAAATCAAAATCACAATGAGACATCACTTTACACCCATTAAAATGGCCATAATCAAAACGACAAGTGTTGGTGATGATGTAGAGACATTAGAACACTGAAATTGTTGGAAGAATGTAAAGTGGTGCAGATGCTTTGGAAAACAGTTTAGCAGTTCCTCAAGATGTTAAATGTGGAGTTACCAGATGACTCAGCAATTCCACTCCTAAGTCTATACCCAAAAAAGGCAGAAACAAATGTCCATATGAAAACTTGTACATGAATGCTCATAATGTTCATAGGAACATTGTTCATAATGGCCAAAAATGTGAAAACAGCCCATATACCCATCAACTGATGAACAGATGAATTAGATGTGGTATAGCCATACAATAAATTATTATTCAGTAATAAAAAGGAATGAAATACTGATAAATGCTACAAAATATTAGAACCTTGAAAATGTTATTCCAAGTGAAATAAGCCAGTCACAAAAGACCACATATTGTACAATTCAATTTATATGAAGTGTCCAGAACAGGTAAATCTACATTTAGAGAAAGTAGATTAGTGGCTGCCTAGGGCTAGGAAATGTGAGGAGAAATGGAAAGTGACTGAAAATGGGTATGGGGTTTCTTTTGGGAGTTATGAAAATGTTCTGAAATTGATAGTGGTGATGGTTGCACAACTCAATAATATACTTAAAACTATTGAATTGTACATTTTAATTATGCAAATTGTATGGTAGGTGAGTTTTATTTCAATATTTATATCCACACACACCTACACATAGAATTATATGTATATGTTTACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACATATATATATATATATGTGTCCAAAGCAAATTCATATTAAAGTGGGGGCAATGTCAAGTATAGAAAACCACCCACAGATACTCCTCTGCTTTAGCCTAACATGTGGCTGTGTGACCAAAGGTACTGTGAAAAGCAATTAGATGGTGTTTTCTGAAAAAAAATTTTATTGAGGTATAATTTACATGTGACAAAGTACTCCCATTTCAGTTCATAGTTTGATGTGTTTTCACAAATGTGACCACCATATAACCAACACATTCAAGATACAGAATATTTTTATTACCCCAAAAAGTCCCTTGTGCCCCTCTGTCTCAAAATGCCCAACCCTAGGCAACAATTGATCTACTTTATGTCATTTTAAGTAAGTTTTGCCCTTTTCTATAATTCCAGATAAATTAAATCCTACAGCATGTACTATTTGGGACCTGGACTTTTTTATAACTCAGGATAATATATTTGAGATTCAACCATGTGTCATGCATATCTCTAATACATTGCTTTTTTATTGCTGAGAGTATTCCCTTATATAAATAGACTAAAGTTTGTTTTGCACTCATCTGCTTAAGGACATTTGATATTTTTCCCTCATTTTAGTTATTATGAACACTGATATACAAGTTTTTGTGTGAACATATGTTTTCACTGCTCTTTGGTAAATGAACAGAAGTGGAAACACTAGGTCTTATAAGTGTATGCCTAACTTTATAAGAAACTGCCAACCTGATTTCCAAAATGTTAATACTATTCTACATACCCACAAGCAATATATGTAAGTCTTTTTAATTGTATTCATATAGTGGGTATCTCATGTAGTTTTCAATTGCCTTTCCTTGATGACTAATTAAATGGAACATCTTTTCATGTGCCTTTGGCCATTCATGTGTGCGTGTAAAGTGTCTGTCCAAATCTTTTGCCTATTTAAAAAATTTATTTTTAATTGAGTTGTATAAGTTTTTTTTAATACATTCTGGATTCAAACCTTTATCAGCTTAGTCTGTGGCTAAAAATTTCATTTTCTTAATGGTGTCTTTCTTAATAGTGCCTTTGATAAAGTCTAATGTATAATTTTTTCTTTTATGTTTCAAATGTTTTGTGTCGTAAGAAATCTTCGCATATGCCAATGTTGAAAAACTTCTAGTTTTACAGTTTTAATTTTTATGTTTCAGTATACTACCTATTTCAAGTTAATTTTTGAGTCTACAGTAAAGGGTTGAAGTTCATTTTTTGTATATGAATATCCAATTTTGTAGAACCATTTGTTGAAAGCCTATTTCCCCACTAAAATATCTTCTTAACAACATTTAATCACAAGATTCTTCATTTCCCTTTTATAGTCACACCCACTTCCTTCCAACTTTCCTTTAATCCTCTTCTCATTAACTCCTACCAACCACTAATCTGTTTTCCCTTTCTATAATTTGGTCATTTCAAGAATATTGACTATATGGAATCATAAAGTATATAACCTTTTGGGATTTGCTGTTTATTCTTTGCATTTATCCATGTATGATGTTTTTCCTTCATTTGTATAGATCTAAATTTCATTGATAGTATTTGCCTTGCATCTGAAGAACTTGCATTTTAAGTCAGCTGGTGAATAATTCTGTCAGCTTTTGTTTGCCTGAAAAAGTTTTTATTTCATATTTATTTTTGAATGGTATTTTTATTGGATATAGAATTCTAGGTTGACAGTTTGCTGTTTTTGTTACAGCTCTTTAAAGACGTCATGTCATTTTCTTCTGATTTAAAAGTTTCTGACAAGACATATGTGAGTATTGTTATCTTTGTTCCTCTGTATGTAATTTTTTTGTCAGCTCTTAAAATTTTCTCTTTATCAATTTTGTTCAGTAATTTGATCATGAACTCCTTTGGTGTGATTTTATTTTGTGTTTATCCTTCTTGGAGTTGTTGACCTGCTTGGATCTATGAGTTTATAATTTTCATAAAATATGAAAAGTTTTTAGCCACTACTTGTGATATTTTTTCTGCCCTTCATCCTTTCTGGGACTCCAGTGATATGCATATTTACAATAGCTGCTTAAAAGACCTTGTTTGTTAATTCTATTTTCTCTGTCATTTTAGGTCTATTTCTGTTAACTGATTTTTCTCCTAGTTATAAGTCGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGCTTTTAGGCATGCCTGGTAATTTTGGATTGGATGCTGGACATTGCGCCTTCATATTGTTGAATGCTGGATATTGTCCTCTTTAATGGATGTTGAACTGTGCTCTTACTGGCAGTTAACTTAATTACATATCAGCTTGATCCTTTTTTAGGCTTTATTAAAACTTTATTAAGTAGACTTTACTCTAGGGCTTATTTAGTCCTATAACTAAGCTGTGACTTATTTTGGAATGCCCTCAATATTAAGCAAGGACCCTAAATTTACCCTGGCTGGTCATAACTCAAACTTCTACCAGCCCTGTATTGCCTCTGGAAATATTCAACTTACAGATACCTGGTAGTTCTTTGCCTGGCTTGTGCAATTTCAGCCTACATATAGCAGTCAGCTGTAGTTACAAGAGGAATGCTATAAAGATCCTCAGCATTTTCTCTACTGAGCACATTCCAGCCACTCAGCCTCTTCAAATTCAAATTTTTGTCTTCTCAACTCTGTGATATCATGCTCTTCTTGAGTGTGTATTGTGGTCCAGAAAGTATCTCCAGGCAGAAAGTTGGTATTATCATAGGTCTTATCTCATTTGTTTCCTTTCTCTGAGGAGTCACAGAACTGTACTAATTACCAAAAGGAGTTTTTTTCATAGATTTTTGTCTGGTTTTCTAGTTGTTTACAGTAAGAGAATAAGTCCAACTCCATTCACTCTCTTGTGTCTGGAAGTAGAAATCACTGATATTATCTATGTTAATACAGTGAAAAAACATCCAGTGTTGTCCCTCTTTCCATCCTCACCCCCACACCTCCACCACTAATACTGTCTCAGTGATGTGCAATATCCAAGGCTTGATTTAGGTCTAATGAATATCTCTCAACACAGAACACTTTGGGTTTCCCAGCACAAGAATTGAAAAAAGCACATGGTACTCTCCCAGCTGAGATTCTTAGCCTCTTTTTTCCCCTACTGTGAGCAGTGTCACCCAGGTGCCCTCACTCATCTATTTTAAATACACTCACCATCTCTGCTAACAGCTTCAGCCTCTGTTAATCAGGTAGCTTTTCATTAATGTTCTTATCCTTGTCCCAGCATCTTATTTGTCATGCTTTATTAGTAGACATGATAAGTCATAAATCTTAGTTCCTCTTAGCTTCTTAGTATCTGTTGTCAAGTTGAAGATCCCAGACAGAGGGAGATGAGAACTGGTTCATTACAGAGTGACTCTTTCTAATATCTCCTTGGTTCTTTATGATACTAATACATTCTTCCCACTGCAGTTGCCTTTTTCTCTATTTAGCTCCAATACAATTCATAGAAATGAGATCATTCGGCTTAAGGGTACATTATCTTCACTTCAACCCATCCTTCTTTAAGATGAACAATGCTGCCTTTAGATTCTGATACTGGCTCTGCCACTTATTAGCTGGATAGCCCCAGACAATTTACTGACTCTGAGTTTGTTTCCATACTTATGGAATAGGGAAAATATATTCTGCATATCTCATGGAGTGGCAACAAAAGCCAAAATTGACAAATGGGATCTAATTAAACTAAAGAGCTTCTGCACAGCAAAAGAAACTACCATCAGAGTGAACAGGCAACCTACAGAATGGGAGAAAATCTTCACAACCTATTCATCTGACAAAGGGCTAATATCCAGAATCTACAATGAATGCAAACAAATTTACAAGACAAAAACAAACAACCCCATCAAAAAGTGGGCAAAGGACATGAACAGACACTTCTCTAAAGAAGACATTTATGCAGACAAAAAACACATGAAAAAATGCTCACCATCACTGGCCAACAGAGAAATGCAAATCAAAACCACAATGAGATACCATCTCACACCAGTTAGAATGGCAATCATTAAAAAGTCAGGAAACAACAACTGCTGGAGAGGATGTGGAGAAATAGGAACACTTTTACACTGTTGGTGGGACTGTAAACCAGTTCAACCATTGTGGAAGTCAGTGTGGCAATTCCTCAGGGATCTAGAACTAGAAATACCATTTGACCCAGCCACCCCATTACTGGGTATATACACAAAGGACTATAAATCATGCTGCTATAAAGACACATGCACACGTATGTTTATTGCGGCATTATTCACAATAGCAAAGACTTGGAACCAATCCAAATGTCCAACAAAGATAGACTGGATTAAGAAAATGTGGCACATATACACCATGGAATACTATGCAGCCATAAAAAAGGATGAGTTCATGTCCTTTGTAGGGACATGGATGAAACTGGAAATCATCATTCTCAGTAAACTATCGCAAGAACAAAAAACCAAACACCGCATATTCTCACTCATAGGTGGGAATTGAACAATGAGAACACATGGACACAGGAAGGGGAACATCACACTCTGGGGACTGTTGTGGGGTGGGGGGAGGGGGGAGGGATAGCATTGGGAGATATACCTAATGCTAGAGGACGAGTTAGTGGGTGCAGCGCACCAGCATGTCACATGTATACATATGTAACTAACCTGCACATTGTGCAGATGTACCCCAAAACTTAAAGTATAATAATAATAAATTAAAAAAAACAAAATATATACATAATATGATCTCGGCTATGGAAAAGAAAAACATTCAGTGGAAAAAAGCTTAAAGGGAAGAGCACCAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGATCAAGCAAGATAATCGATGTTAAGTACTTTATATAGTGCCTGTACCATGGTAAATGCTTAATAATTGTTAGCTATGATGACAATAATGATGATTAAAATGGTCTTTCCATACACTCTGCATACCATCCCTCTGACTGACCTGATGATTATAATTATTCCCTAACTACTAGCAAAGAAGCTTCAATCTCCCTTCACTTCTGCTTTTAAACAGTTTTCTCCTATTTTACAAAAAAGAGTGTGTCCTTTTCTTCCCTTTTCCAGCTCTTCATAAACACAGTGTATTAGTCCATTCCTTCATTGCTATAAATAAATACCTGAGACTGGGTAATTTATAAAGAAAAGAGGTTTAATTGTCTCATGGTTCTGCAGGCTGTACAGAAAGCACGATGCTGACATCTGCTCAGCTTCTGGGGAGTCCTCAGGAAACTTACAATCATGGCAAAAGGTAAAGGGGGAGCAAGGTGTCTTAC  A   100 PASS    CLUSTER_NUM=25425;CONTIG=TGGAAGGCAACTGTCGTTTAAGATGAAAAACAGTGATAACTGCTGAGAAATCTCAGCCTTAAGTGTGTTGAAAGTTGATAATGTCCATCTATGTGGTGAACAATTTGTGAAACAAGACTGTCAAAGAGAGTTATAGGTTCTTGGAAGTAAGAGGCAACATCTTATGATCAAGCTGTTGGGTTATCTCTTTATGATCTTCAACTACACTAAGAAGTGTGTCAATTGTATTCAGAATTCCCATAGCAGTAACTGCTTTGTCATCACTACCTTCTTCATCTGGCCCTGTCTGGATTACTTGGCTAAATGTCATTGCCAACTGTTGTGTCATTTCTACTGCAATAGGAGTAACTTCTTCACTATTTTCACAGATCATTTTCTGAATTACATTGGTAAGGTCATCATTTTCTGTTTCTGTTATAATATGAAGAAGAGCCTGCATTACAGGTCTGATAAATGCTGTGATACATTCTTTAGATTTTTCTTGATTGCTGATAAATACTTGAAGGACAATGGCAGCTTCCACTTTCACAGGCATGTCTCTGTCATCAATCAGACA;CONTIG_NUM=24722;DOWNSTREAM=TCAAGCTGTTGGGTTATCTCTTTATGATCTTCAACTACACTAAGAAGTGTGTCAATTGTATTCAGAATTCCCATAGCAGTAACTGCTTTGTCATCACTACCTTCTTCATCTGGCCCTGTCTGGATTACTTGGCTAAATGTCATTGCCAACTGTTGTGTCATTTCTACTGCAATAGGAGTAACTTCTTCACTATTTTCACAGATCATTTTCTGAATTACATTGGTAAGGTCATCATTTTCTGTTTCTGTTATAATATGAAGAAGAGCCTGCATTACAGGTCTGATAAATGCTGTGATACATTCTTTAGATTTTTCTTGATTGCTGATAAATACTTGAAGGACAATGGCAGCTTCCACTTTCACAGGCATGTCTCTGTCATCAATCAGACA;END=211033725;NS=1;READSOURCES=(0:33:68,1:0:69);SOMATICSCORE=60;SVLEN=-12257;SVTYPE=DEL;UPSTREAM=TGGAAGGCAACTGTCGTTTAAGATGAAAAACAGTGATAACTGCTGAGAAATCTCAGCCTTAAGTGTGTTGAAAGTTGATAATGTCCATCTATGTGGTGAACAATTTGTGAAACAAGACTGTCAAAGAGAGTTATAGGTTCTTGGAAGTAAGAGGCAACATCTTATGA;ensembl_gene_id=ENSG00000143473    GT:GQ   1/.:.
chr1    249175897   chr1uGROUPERuDELu4u25993    CCATACTGAACTATTAAAGTTATTTGAAATGACAATTGTAATAATATCTTCCTTGAGGAGTTCTACAATCTTTGCTGTTATTTCTTTAAGTCCTTCCTTTAATGAGTACTGTTTGGTGCATGTAACCTGCTGTGGTGTAGACAGTGTTATGGACTTCATTTTAATTTGAACTAGGTTAGAAAATTTTAGTTCCTCTAGTTTCCTTTAATATAAGTTAAAAAGATTTGGAATAAAATTCATTCCTGTAATGTCTTATAATTTGGGTGAGCAGTAAAAAGTGCATAGAGCAGTATAGAAGCAGAGG    C   100 PASS    CLUSTER_NUM=140439;CONTIG=TACTGAACTATTTAGATATCCCTGTGGTAATGTTTTGAATTGGTATTGTTTACCTTCCCATGTAAAGTTGGTATATTCCTGGCTTGCTTTATTTATTGGTTTGGCAAAGAACACATCTGACATGTCTATGATTGTATAGTATTTGTCATTATGATTAATGATCTTATTAACTAGCTCTTCTACATCTGGTAATGCTCTTGGCATTTTAGTTGAGACTTTATTTAAATTTCTATAGTCAATAGTTAATCTATAGCTCCTGTTTGTTTTTAAGACAGGCCAAGAAAGCTTCAAGTTTATTTACCTCTGAGTCCTTCTGTATGAATGTTTATTGTGGGATCTGGCCAGCAGCCCGCAATGCAATGGGGCTCTCTCTTTGTTCCCAGGCAGATCGGCAGGTTGAGAAATAATAGACACACACAAGATAGTGAAAGCTGGGTCCAGGGGGGTCACCGCCTTCTGGTCCCACGGAGCCAAAAATGCACGGGATATACCAGCATTTATTATTAAGTTTAGTGAGGGCAGGGGTAGGTTAGTGAGGGATTTAGGGTCATTTGATTATGAGGTTAGATGGTCACATGGGGATGAAGTAATTCTTTAACATAACATCTGTATGCAGAAGTACAGTAT;CONTIG_NUM=136911;DOWNSTREAM=CAAGAAAGCTTCAAGTTTATTTACCTCTGAGTCCTTCTGTATGAATGTTTATTGTGGGATCTGGCCAGCAGCCCGCAATGCAATGGGGCTCTCTCTTTGTTCCCAGGCAGATCGGCAGGTTGAGAAATAATAGACACACACAAGATAGTGAAAGCTGGGTCCAGGGGGGTCACCGCCTTCTGGTCCCACGGAGCCAAAAATGCACGGGATATACCAGCATTTATTATTAAGTTTAGTGAGGGCAGGGGTAGGTTAGTGAGGGATTTAGGGTCATTTGATTATGAGGTTAGATGGTCACATGGGGATGAAGTAATTCTTTAACATAACATCTGTATGCAGAAGTACAGTAT;END=249176200;NS=1;READSOURCES=(0:44:63,1:0:64);SOMATICSCORE=60;SVLEN=-303;SVTYPE=DEL;UPSTREAM=TACTGAACTATTTAGATATCCCTGTGGTAATGTTTTGAATTGGTATTGTTTACCTTCCCATGTAAAGTTGGTATATTCCTGGCTTGCTTTATTTATTGGTTTGGCAAAGAACACATCTGACATGTCTATGATTGTATAGTATTTGTCATTATGATTAATGATCTTATTAACTAGCTCTTCTACATCTGGTAATGCTCTTGGCATTTTAGTTGAGACTTTATTTAAATTTCTATAGTCAATAGTTAATCTATAGCTCCTGTTTGTTTTTAAGACAGGC  GT:GQ   1/.:.
chr10   20219603    chr10uGROUPERuDELu0u11231   AAAAAAAGGCTGGCACGGTGGCTCACACCTGTAAATCCCAGCACTTTGGGAGGCCGAGGTGGGTGGGTCACCTGAGGTTGG   A   47  PASS    CLUSTER_NUM=60987;CONTIG=GTATACTGATTTTGGAAAATATGTCAGCTCAATTTGGAAGATTGCTAAACCACCTAAAACAGAGCCTGTTTAAAAAATAAATAAATAAAAAATAATAGTTCAAGGCCAGCCTGACCAACAAGGTGAAATCCCATCTCTACTAAAACTACAAAAATTAGC;CONTIG_NUM=59978;DOWNSTREAM=GAGTTCAAGGCCAGCCTGACCAACAAGGTGAAATCCCATCTCTACTAAAACTACAAAAATTAGC;END=20219683;NS=1;READSOURCES=(0:7:18,1:0:60);SOMATICSCORE=40;SVLEN=-80;SVTYPE=DEL;UPSTREAM=GTATACTGATTTTGGAAAATATGTCAGCTCAATTTGGAAGATTGCTAAACCACCTAAAACAGAGCCTGTTTAAAAAATAAATAAATAAAAAATAA;ensembl_gene_id=ENSG00000120594   GT:GQ   1/.:.
chr11   56932527    chr11uGROUPERuDELu1u8703    CCAGAGCACATCATGAGATCCTGGAGCCAGACCTAGAAACCTATTAAACAAGGGAACCCCAGCATGTCTCATTTATTACCCAAAGGAAGGAAATTAGCATCACATGTATAAAGCACTCAGTAGTCTATAAAATGCTCTTAGCAATTCACTTCGTGAGGAAGTGCCTTTTCCCACTTCCACAGAGGGATACCGAGCCTCAAGGGATTAGGAGACTAATCCAGGCTCACACAGCTGATAAGGAACAGCCCAGACATTTTGGCCCAGTGCTGCTAGCCCTCAATCTGGTGCTTTGCCCTCTGCACCGCCTGCCATGCAGGGAATACATGTTAATATCTCTCTGTATTAGTCTGTTCTCATGCTGCTAATAAAGACATACCCAAGACTGGTTAATTTATAAAGGAAAGAGGTTTAACTGAATCACAGTTGCACATGGCTGGCATCATGGTGGAATGCAAAGGAGGAGCAAGGCCACATCTCACATGGTGGCAGGCAAGAGGGCATGTGCAGGGGAACTCCCCTTTATAAAACCATCAGCTCTCTGCTGGGTGTGGTGGCTCACACCTGTAATCCCAGCACTTTGGGAGGCCGAGACGGGTGGATCACCTGAAGTCAGGAGTTCGAGAACAGTCTGGCCAACATGGCGAAACCCCATCTCTATTAAAAATACAAAAAAAAATTAGTTGGGCGTGGCAGTGAGTGCCTGTAATCCCAGCTACTCGAGAGGCTGAGGCAGGAGAATCACCTGAGCCCAGGAGGCAGAGGTTGCAGTGAGCCAAGATCACGCCACTGCACTCCAGCCTGGGTGATAAGAGTGAAACTCGGTCTCAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATCACATCTCACGAGACTTATTCACTATCATGAGAACAGCATGGGAAAACCCTGCCCCCATGATTCAATTACCTCCCACTGGGTCCCTCCTATGACATGTGGGGATTATTACAATTCATGGTGAGATTTGGGTGGGGACACAAAGCCAAACCATATCACTCTCTTTCTTGGCCACAGGTGGACTTGAAAAACCCTTTCCCTTAACCAAGCAGGAGCCCCAGTAGCTGCTTTGTTCAACGTCTGTTTCTCTAAGGTCTCCTACTCTGGAATATTTAGGAAAACCCAAGGTGGCTCAAAAAGATCATCCCTGTACCAAGCCTCAGGGATTCTAGTGTGACCCAACCTCTCCCAGTCCCTATAGGCATCTCTTTCAAACATCAGAACTGGTGCAGACTCAATAGAAGAAAGGTGTGACTCCAAGATGTCCTCCCTCACAGCCCTTTATCACAATGGGGCTCTCTTCACCGTAGAAGGGAAGGCTGAGGCTCAGAAATATGGTGTAGGCTTGGACTTTGGAAGGAGAATGACTAAGCTGAAGTTCTTCCTCTGCCATTTACAAGCTGTGTGACTTTGGAAAACTTTCTTAATGTTTTTGCTTTTAATTTCCTCATGTATAAAAGATGGGGTTGTCATACTTAGGTTTAAGACTATTGCACGTGCCTGTAATTCTAGCACTTTGGGAGGCCGAGGTGGGCAGATCACTTGAGGTCAGGAGTTTGAGACCAGCTGGCCAACATGGTGAAACACCATCGCTACTAAAAATATAAAAATTAGCCAGGCATGGTGATGCATGCCTGTAATCCCAGCTACTCGGGAGGCTGAGGCAGGAGATTCGCTTGAACCTGGGACGTGGAGGTTGCGTTGAGGCAAGATCACGCCACTGCACTCCAGCCTGGGCAACAGAATGAGACTCCACCTCAAAAAAATAGAAGACTATTGCAAAGATTTTAAAAGATGGCACAGGTACAACACTGAACACAGTGTTTCATGAGTGACAGTCATAAGCTTTTCTACCACCTAACTGTGTTACTTTTAGCAAACTACCTAATTTATCTCGGCCTCGGTTGTTTTGTGATTCTTTTCAAGGGAAAAAAAAAGCACCTCCCTTCATAAGCCTGCTATAAGAACAATATAAAATAGTTGACATAAAGCACTTAATCTCTTGCCTGTCACAGGAAAGGTGCTCAACACCTGTTAGCTCTGTGTTGATGTCCCCAGATCAGAGAGCCAGAAAAGGAGGGCTAAAGTTCCAACCAGGATCTTCTGGTTCCAACCCAGCAGCACCTGAGCAAGGTTGATAATGGTAAAGAAAAGAAGAAATAAGCAATAGGGGCCTCACAAACACAGGCAGGAATAAATCACTCCCATGTGGCAGTTTTCTGTGCCTGACCCAAGAGATAGGTGTTGCACCTTTATCCATGTGGACAGATAAGAAAGAGCAAAGGGCATAGGTCACAGAGGTGAGTATGACCTCATTGCAGTGCCAGGATATTTCCAGGCAATTGGCAAGACTTATTGACAATCATCCAATAAATAGGATAAATAGTTCTTACTTCCCAAGTGCCTGGGAAGAGAGCTTGCAGCTCTTTCCAATTCCTGCCTCTCATCTCTTCCTCCTCGGACACTGCAGCTCTCCGTTTCTGGAAAATCTCAGGGCAGAATCTGGGCTCCTTCCCACTTTCCTCTGTCCAGAATTCTAAGGATGCCTGGGAGAAGGCATCTGCCCTGAATGAATGGGTCAGAGGCATGATTCCAAGTGACTGGCTGGTAATTGGAAGAGCTCAGTGGTCTGGCTGGGGAGATGAGAGCCTGCTAAGCACATCTGGCCAGCATCAGAATCACAAATTGAAGAGAGCTTGGAAGGACTCAGCCCCCACTGACATTCACAAAGGAAGGAAAATGTAGGGAGCCAGACAGAAAGGAGTGATGCTCTTCAAAGTCAACAGGCTTATAACAAACACCATCTCATAGGTGAAAGTGGGAGCACAGAACAGGCACACTCAGCTAACACACAGCTTTCTGAGGGAGGTCATCCTCCACCAAATGAAAATAGCCCTGCTTTTTCATTTTTTAATTTTTATTAATTTTTAAATCAACAAATAAAAATTATATATATTGGCCAGGTACAGTGGTTCATGCCTATAATCCCAGCACTTTGGGACGCCAAGGCAGGAGAACCACTTGAGACCAGGAGTTCAAGACCAGCCTGGACAACATAGTGAGATCCCATCACTACAAAAGAAAAAATATTTAAGGAAAAAAATTGTATATATTTATGGCATACGATGTGAAGTTTTGACATATCTACACATTGTGAAATGATTAAATCAAGCTAATTAACATATCCATCATGCCACATCCTTAAATTTTTATGGTGAGAACATTTAAGATCTATCTCAGCAATTTTGAAGTGCATGCTATTGTCACCATGCTACACAATAGACATCCAGAATTTATTCATCTTGTCTAGCTGAAACATTGTATCCTTTGACCAACATCTCCATACCTCTCCTGCATACCTCCCAGCCCCTGGTAACCATTATTCTCCTCTGCTGCTATGAGTTCGATTTGTTCGGATTCCACATATAAATAAGATCGTGCAATATATTTCTGTTTATGCCTGGCTTATTTCACTTAGCAAAATGTCCTCCAGTTTCATCCATGTTGTCACAAATGACAAGATCTCCTTCTTTTTTAAGACTGAATAGTATTCTATTGTGTACATGTACCACATTTTCTTTATCTGCTGTATTAGTCTGTTTTCACACTGCTGATAAAGACATATCCAAAACTGGGAACAAAAAGAGGTTTAATTGGACTTACAGTTCCACATGGCTGGAGACGCCTCAGAATCATCACAGGAGGTGAAAGGCAGTTCTTACATAGCAGCAGCAAGAAAAAATGAGGAGGAAGCAAAAGCAGAAACCCCTGATAAACCCATCAGATCTCATGAGACTTATTCACTATCACGAGAATAGCACGGGAAAGACCGGCCCCCATGATTCAATTACACACTCCCCGCCCCTGCTGGGTCCCTTCCACAACACGTGGGAATTCTGGACAATATAATTCAAGTTGAGATTTTGGTGGGGACACAGCCAAACCGTATCAT C   100 PASS    CLUSTER_NUM=52260;CONTIG=CTTCTACCCCTGGCAGTGCAAAGTCCAGGACCAGGCAGGTGGGGGGTGCTGGAAAAGTTAGCAATTGAGTGATTGTACAGCCAATTTGTCACTTTCATGGGATCGGAGTGAGGCTATCTCAGAATCTTCTGTATCTACTTCATCTCTTGCTCTTTCCATTCTTTGATACTTTGACACATCCACATCCACTGCTCCTGGCCCCTCCGAATCTCATGTCCTCACATTTCAAAATCAATCATGCCTTCCCAACAGTCCCCCAAAGTCTTAACTTATTTCAGCATTAATCCAAAAGTCCACAGTCCAAAGTCTTATCTGAGACAAGGCAAGTCCCTTTCACCTATGAGCCTGCAAAATCAAAAGCAAGCTAGTTACTTCCTAGATACAATGGGGATACAGGTACTAAGTAAATACTGCTGATCCAAATGGGAGAAATTGGCCAAAACAAAGGGGCTACAGGGCCCATGCAAGTCT;CONTIG_NUM=52670;DOWNSTREAM=TCTGCTCCTGGCCCCTCCGAATCTCATGTCCTCACATTTCAAAATCAATCATGCCTTCCCAACAGTCCCCCAAAGTCTTAACTTATTTCAGCATTAATCCAAAAGTCCACAGTCCAAAGTCTTATCTGAGACAAGGCAAGTCCCTTTCACCTATGAGCCTGCAAAATCAAAAGCAAGCTAGTTACTTCCTAGATACAATGGGGATACAGGTACTAAGTAAATACTGCTGATCCAAATGGGAGAAATTGGCCAAAACAAAGGGGCTACAGGGCCCATGCAAGTCT;END=56936485;NS=1;READSOURCES=(0:21:23,1:0:65);SOMATICSCORE=60;SVLEN=-3958;SVTYPE=DEL;UPSTREAM=CTTCTACCCCTGGCAGTGCAAAGTCCAGGACCAGGCAGGTGGGGGGTGCTGGAAAAGTTAGCAATTGAGTGATTGTACAGCCAATTTGTCACTTTCATGGGATCGGAGTGAGGCTATCTCAGAATCTTCTGTATCTACTTCATCTCTTGCTCTTTCCATTCTTTGATACTTTGACACATCCACATCC    GT:GQ   1/.:.
```

I used a code:

```
out = open('/home/istolarek/OUTintersectPT','w')
masterlist = [row for row in Pt]
for line in a:
    g=[]
    if line.startswith('chr'):
        line = line.strip().split()
        g.append(line[0])
##        print line[0]
##print len(w)
    for row in masterlist:
        row = row.strip().split()
        f = range(int(row[1]),int(row[2]))
        w=[]
        for i in g:
            if i == row[0]:
                w.append(int(line[1]))
                for i in w:
##            print line[0],row[0],line[1]
##            out.write(str(line[0])+'\t'+str(row[0])+'\t'+str(line[1])+'\t'+str(f)+'\n')
                    if int(i) in f:
                        out.write(str(line)+'\n')
                    else:
                        break
            else:
                break
out.close()
```

This code seems to work, but takes far too much time.

So if column 1 in both files matches, go to comparing second column. Second column from file a is just a number (line[1]), in file Pt it is a range of values f = range(int(row[1]),int(row[2])). So if the first condition about matching columns 1 (these with chr values) and if values from second column from file a are in the range of f, I want to write these lines to the output.

I wrote another one:

I wrote:

```
masterlist = [row for row in Pt]

for line in a:
    line = line.strip().split()
    for row in masterlist:
        row = row.strip().split()
        b = int(line[1])
        f = range(int(row[1]),int(row[2]))
        if (line[0] == row[0]):
            if a in f:
                print b,f
```

These both should be a match. But the script only reports the first ontry from Pt file. If the first entry is not matched, the output is none. I want the script to output all matches

I'm fighting with this for quite some time.

Comment: I've noticed column 3 of `a` contains data that might belong on a separate row of `Pt`. Is this intentional? Also, should the files have different numbers of columns?

Comment: So, what goes wrong? What do you get instead of your expected result?

Comment: There should be no need for the line `for i in g`: you only need to compare each element of `g` once to the rows in your masterlist. Currently, if a line from `a` matches, it will be matched again and again in every next iteration. `if line[0] == row[0]` makes more sense in the next line.

Comment: @icedwater both files are tab delibited, so the column 3 does not interfere with column 2 in a file. It's probably fault of formatting, that it looks like that

Comment: @Evert Now the script takes like forever to complete (started 15 hours ago, and now have only 5 lines in the output). Iwas trying different scripts, that weren't working as I wanted, so I posted only the one that actually is doing what I want. I will edit a post a bit, since it's actually a problem of optimizing the script now.

Comment: @Evert Yes I had another script (just added after editing) which uses if line[0] == row[0]. However there is no output after the last if statement.

Comment: Depending on the file sizes, all those loops within loops within loops within ... would take quite an amount of time. Plus, your arrays might grow too large to hold in memory and you would get lots of disk swapping.

Comment: did you already debug and check if all your parsing works correctly (i.e. the contents of `line`, `row` after strip-split)?

Comment: also, why `for i in w:`, when `w` can only have one element anyway?

Comment: Is that second script really giving you no output at all? That would mean `masterlist` is empty...

Comment: another thing: instead of `if (int(i) in f):` it may be faster to compare with the limits instead` if (i>=row[1] && i<=row[2])`?

Comment: also, why the need for the `masterlist`? wouldn't just `for row in Pt:` be sufficient?

Comment: @Christoph I think `for row in Pt:` would only do the complete loop once, then the file pointer is at its end; so any second time we get there, it won't loop. I think `Pt.seek(0)` before the loop isn't something the OP is aware of.

Comment: Any change you could edit your post to include the two data files, at least the first 10-20 rows of each? Preferably with all the possible cases, so that people can run your code as a fully fledged example.

Comment: If you removed the two `else:` `break` statements do you get all matches?

Comment: Ok. I added more lines from both files. And also gave another exaple (simplified) of the code. It still reports only 1 match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all, you are looping on `a`, but you assigned a value to `a` inside the loop, so it's not likely to get very far.

Second of all, I believe that `strip().split()` is redundant.  You don't need `strip()` because it's implied in `split()`.

Third of all, you should only `split` each line in the master file once.  You are doing that for each line of input, which is bound to increase processing time a bit.

I am not entirely certain I understand your requirements from your code, but it seems to me something along these lines should help you:

```
import sys
from collections import defaultdict
master = defaultdict(list)
with open('Pt') as Pt:
    for entry in Pt:
        n, low, high = entry.split()
        master[n].append(map(int, (low, high)))

with open('a') as a:
    for line in a:
        n, i = line.split()[:2]
        for low, high in master[n]:
            if low <= int(i) <= high:
                sys.stdout.write(line)
                break
```

To explain: First read and process all the data in the master file just once.  Storing the master data in a [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is handy here because it allows you to scan only the rows that matched the first column.  `map(int, ...)` converts to ints.

When processing the input file, we can retrieve the ranges against which to compare the second value using the first value.  Since `master` is a `defaultdict(list)`, if there are no matches for the first column, we'll end up iterating an empty list.

Note that your original code using `range()` would have been equivalent to a condition

```
low <= i < high
```

You'll have to adjust the comparison operators as needed.

**UPDATE** oops.  I put the `break` outside the condition.  After fixing it I get the following three items:

```
chr1    1161693 chr1uGROUPERuDELu0u832  TGCTCTTTCCAGAAACCCTCAACCCTGTACGGTCAGGAGGAAACATGGCACCTCCCCTCTGGGG    T   63  NormalSupport;MinSampleCount;LowSomaticScore    CLUSTER_NUM=5454;CONTIG=GGTGCAGGGAAGCAGGAAGGAAGTGAAGCTCAAAAGCCCCTAGGACAGGGCACCTCCCCTCTGGATGCTCTTTCCAGAAACCCTCAACCTTGTACGGTCAGGAGAAAACACATCCCACAAG;CONTIG_NUM=5840;DOWNSTREAM=GCTCTTTCCAGAAACCCTCAACCCTGTACGGTCAGGAGAAAACACATCCCACAAG;END=1161756;NS=1;READSOURCES=(0:3:0,1:2:13);SOMATICSCORE=19;SVLEN=-63;SVTYPE=DEL;UPSTREAM=GGTGCAGGGAAGCGGGAAGGAAGTGAAGCTCAAAAGCCCCTAGGACAGGGCACCTCCCCTCTGGAT;ensembl_gene_id=ENSG00000078808   GT:GQ   1/.:.
chr1    158851689   chr1uGROUPERuDELu3u4452 GGGGAGTAATTCTTATTCATGATATGAAAACTCTAATGTGTTTCTTATTCCAGAAAA   G   100 NormalSupport   CLUSTER_NUM=25182;CONTIG=CATATTTTGCTATATCTCACATCATTGTTCATCTGATAATATATGAAAACTACAATGTGTTTCTTATTCCAGAAAGGGGAGTAATTCTTATTCATGAATAAACACTGAAGGAGAAAGATTATGGATCATAGTGGGAAAAGCCACAATACCATCTACATTC;CONTIG_NUM=24300;DOWNSTREAM=GGGAGTAATTCTTATTCATGAATAAACACTGACGGAGAAAGATTATGGATCATAGTGGGAAAAGCCACAATACCATCTACATTC;END=158851745;NS=1;READSOURCES=(0:11:0,1:3:18);SOMATICSCORE=55;SVLEN=-56;SVTYPE=DEL;UPSTREAM=CATATTTTGCTATATCTCACATCATTGTTCATCTGATAATATATGAAAACTCCAATGTGTTTCTTATTCCAGAAAG;ensembl_gene_id=ENSG00000229849    GT:GQ   1/.:.
chr1    165014865   chr1uGROUPERuDELu3u7344 ACTGGCATTAGCTATGCTTCCTTAGGCAGACAGCATGTTGAGAAATTCACATTCATCAG A   100 NormalSupport   CLUSTER_NUM=40249;CONTIG=CTCCAGTAAAGAGCATCTTTTAATGAAGTGTATCTGCCTGGGCTAGAAAGGCAGCTGCCTCCACTAAAGCAGGGCTGGTCCAGAAATATTACCACTTGCCTAATCCTTATAGTAATCCTAACTGGCAGGTATTATTATATCCCAATTCACACACTTAGAGG;CONTIG_NUM=38845;DOWNSTREAM=CTTGCCTAATCCTTATAGTAATCCTAACTGGCAGGTATTATTATATCCCAATTCACACACTTAGAGG;END=165014923;NS=1;READSOURCES=(0:32:0,1:9:18);SOMATICSCORE=60;SVLEN=-58;SVTYPE=DEL;UPSTREAM=CTCCAGTAAAGAGCATCTTTTAATGAAGTGTATCTGCCTGGGCTAGAAAGGCAGCTGCCTCCACTAAAGCAGGGCTGGTCCAGAAATATTACCA  GT:GQ   1/.:.
```

Comment: Hmm. To simplify what I intend to do: For column 0 in file a: if it matches the clumn 0 in file Pt, check if the column 1 in file a is i range of values between columns 1 and 2 in file Pt. The code you passed is a bit unclear to me. And is also giving no output in my console

Comment: This is pretty embarasing, but the problem was that I mistook file path. Well at least I optimised the code to it's extent^^
Thank you all for the help

Comment: @Irek thanks and no worries on the upvote.  I realized that converting the first column to int isn't really necessary, so I simplified by removing the [3:] and moving the int conversion lower.

Answer (score 1):

At least, don't do this:

```
row = row.strip().split()
f = range(int(row[1]),int(row[2]))
w=[]
print row[0]
if (line[0] == row[0]):
    w.append(int(line[1]))
    for i in w:
        if (int(i) in f):
```

Instead:

```
f = int(row[1]), int(row[2])
...
        if f[0] <= int(i) <= f[1]:
```

or similar.

Comment: I can't reply to posts yet, so I editted the first once again. The second script is what now I have. Still some problems (described below the code)